# how to disable window7 minimize ability

Tags: python, c++, pywin32

I want to disable all windows minimized ability in win7.I have used  **SetWindowLong** in Python win32gui.

```
from  win32gui import  *
def disablemin(hwnd,HWMD):
   SetWindowLong(hwnd,win32con.GWL_STYLE,GetWindowLong(hwnd,win32con.GWL_STYLE) & ~win32con.WS_MINIMIZEBOX)
EnumWindows(disablemin, 0)
```

But it only made buttons can't be used.I find some windows still can minimize.How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your idea.

1. You're trying to alter the behavior of other windows, windows that aren't yours. This is always a bad idea.
2. You try to alter the window styles once. This isn't necessarily sufficient; they can be restored by the victim process.
3. Even if the window style is altered, it doesn't mean the actual minimize box is gone. This just removes the one created by the OS; manually-drawn icons might still be present.
4. Even if the minimize box is gone, this won't stop calls to `ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE)`

Comment: Sorry,my idea is worry.But I find  **Hook** may  solve it .Is it correct I use **WH_CALLWNDPRO** to intercept message sended to windows?And if I want to achieve my goal,what method is best.